# Classic asp session cookie

Tags: security, cookies, web-applications, asp-classic, session-cookies

Does anyone know what marking the secure and path to a classic asp session cookie particularly when you try and access it.

I am assigning the domain to the fqdn and the path to whatever it is to the application. Can I not access the cookie from the look back 127.0.0.1 because the domain doesn't match?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can only be accessed by the domain that has set it due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Therefore a cookie set on `example.com` cannot be read by the loopback on `127.0.0.1` or anyother domain name or IP address, even if the IP address points to the same server.